# Facing issue while generating pie chart in D3

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to generate pie chart in d3 from external data, I could not find error in the below code as it is not throwing any error.

Here is what my code

```
    //file path is correct  
    d3.json("errortable12.json", function(data){

    //var obj = JSON.parse(data);
    var r= 300; 
    var color =d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["red","blue","orange"])
    console.log(data);

    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                    .attr("width",1500)
                    .attr("height",1500);

    var group = canvas.append("g")
                    .attr("transform","translate(300,300)");

    var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .innerRadius(200)
                .outerRadius(r);

    var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .value(function(d) { return d.age});

    var arcs = group.selectAll(".arc")
                    .data(pie(data))
                    .enter()
                        .append("g")
                        .attr("class","arc");

    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d.age",arc);

    arcs.append("path")
        .attr("d.age",arc)
        .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.data);});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems.  First, "d.age" is not an SVG attribute, just use "d". Also, no need to append two paths, just call that once.  Second, passing `d.data` to color is not valid, just use `i`.

```
arcs.append("path")
    .attr("d.age",arc); //<-- d.age is not a valid SVG attribute

arcs.append("path")
    .attr("d.age",arc) //<-- why repeat this twice?
    .attr("fill",function(d){return color(d.data);});
```

Should just be:

```
     arcs.append("path")
       .attr("d", arc)
       .attr("fill", function(d,i) {
          // return color(d.data);
          return color(i); //<-- just use i
     });
```

Full code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/L2gipNtfjrhE2uWJtNj3?p=preview).

Comment: Thank you very much Mark. Actually I am very new to this and just started learning. :-)